# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined - AWS Cognito

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cognito

"First time posting" so please advise me if I would need to edit the question, I'll try to include to all code related to the problem.

TLDR: I'm using the ***amazon-cognito-identity-js*** to implement user authentication in my app. When trying to implement the method to resend the confirmation email I stumble upon this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'username')

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState();
 const [password, setPassword] = useState();
 const [username, setUsername] = useState();
```

```
const resendConfirmation = () => {
    console.log(username);
    const userData = {
      Username: username,
      Pool: UserPool,
    };
    const cognitoUser = CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.resendConfirmationCode(username, true, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Couldn't resend code");
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        alert('code resent');
      }
    });
  };
```

> Anchor tag that calls resendConfirmation()

```
<form className='login-form' onSubmit={verifyAccount}>
                  Enter the OTP:
                  <label className='email-label'>
                    <div className='div-email'>
                      <input
                        type='text'
                        value={OTP}
                        onChange={(e) => setOTP(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </label>
                  <br />
                  <button className='sign-inbtn' type='submit'>
                    Verify
                  </button>
                  <div className='login-footer'>
                    <p className=''>
                      Request code again?{' '}
                      <a className='' onClick={resendConfirmation}>
                        Resend Code
                      </a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
           </form>
```

```
const verifyAccount = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const user = new CognitoUser({
  Username: username,
  Pool: UserPool,
});
console.log(user);
user.confirmRegistration(OTP, true, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    alert("Couldn't verify account");
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    alert('Account verified successfully');
    window.location.href = '/login';
  }
});
```

I have checked that my username state does actually contain the username, so I'm not sure why Cognito prompts this error.

Comment: Based on the error it seems like the problem is not "username" being undefined but an object you're trying to use which as an attribute called username is undefined.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the issue, the object wasn't defined. The problem was resolved by creating the object first and then passing it. I was confused with how AWS retrieves the user object.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer since the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error it seems like the problem is not "username" being undefined but an object you're trying to use which as an attribute called username is undefined.